# How do I implement a slide-out menu pane similar to Google Maps and Twitter?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Google Maps Slide-Out Pane]

I am looking to implement something similar to the slide-out pane shown in Google Maps and also in Twitter(Click the settings button after performing a search).

The pane displays itself at the bottom and the user can either click on it or swipe upwards to reveal more information.

I want to implement something similar but I am not sure how to proceed. I have a simple ListView and when a user clicks an item, the slide-out pane should appear. How would I go about doing this?

I was thinking of using a context menu but according to the official docs, icons are not allowed to be placed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). It should be perfect for your needs. It can be also achieved using [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a navigation drawer to make a slider menu.

You can see a good example here:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: I actually wanted the NavDrawer to slide out from the bottom of the screen when I click a List Item. I already have one that slides out from the left.